# Clickable phone number and mail in PHP

Tags: php, clickable

**PHP** Hello. I need to add clickable phone number and mail. Can You help?

```
  <?php if(!empty($header_email)): ?>
       <li><span>
         <i class="fa <?php echo esc_attr($header_email_icon);?>"></i></span>
           <?php echo esc_html($header_email);?></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
         <?php if(!empty($header_phone)): ?>
           <li><span><i class="fa <?php echo esc_attr($header_phone_icon);?>"></i></span>     <?php echo esc_html($header_phone);?></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Should I add?

```
<a href="mail"><?php echo esc_html($header_email);?></a> 
<a href="tel"><?php echo esc_html($header_phone);?></a>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use clickable email address you should use like that,

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com">Send email</a>
```

dont delete mailto: part.

And if you want to use clickable phone number you should use like that,

```
<a href="tel:123-456-7890">123-456-7890</a>
```

dont delete tel: part.

Comment: Ok, with mailto, but I need to do it in **PHP**. Pls look above

Comment: Than use like this;
<a href="<?=$header_phone?>"><?=$header_phone?></a>

Comment: It dosn't work.  <a href="<?=$header_phone?>"><?=$header_phone?></a></li>

Comment: It should be `href="mailto:<?= $header_email?>"` and `href="tel:<?= $header_phone ?>"`, assuming that those two variables contains a valid email and a valid phone number.  The client also needs to have some default mail client configured, and a way to make calls for those links to work.